# Lilypond acciaccatura slur position

Tags: lilypond, slurs

Lilypond issue: I'm trying to get the slurs in acciaccatura to look like this (generated in Musescore):
[image]

Notice that the slur is beneath the grace note. However, Lilypond insists on putting the slur above:

[image]

In voice one for the bar in question I have:

```
\acciaccatura   d8(  -4   <c a>4)  -2 -1 <g b>4 e4 \rest |
```

and in the second voice I have:

```
e2  e'4
```

I've tried (and failed) to find something like this in the manual and the snippets.Is it possible to move the slur?

Comment: Does \slurDown work? http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/direction-and-placement#the-direction-property

Comment: Why is the slur in the top picture going **between** the notes in the quarter-note chord next to it instead of just **below** the quarter-note chord?

Comment: Musescore puts the end of the slur *between* the notes of the chord, do you want to replicate that as well?

Comment: @Greg: this kind of works, the slur does go down, but the slur goes to the bottom of the chord rather than the top note (sorry for not making this need clear).

Comment: @Dekkadeci: this is a guitar notation thing. It indicates that a D should be played initially and the pull off goes to the C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me, the easiest change is to include `\once \override Slur #'direction = #DOWN` immediately preceding the `\acciaccatura`. This produces:

[image]

```
\version "2.19.82"

line = \relative c'' {
  \key g \major
  \time 3/4
  <<
    {
      \once \override Slur #'direction = #DOWN
      \acciaccatura d8-4 <c a>4-2-1 <g b>4 r4 | 
    }
    \\
    {
      e,2 e'4 |
    }
  >>
}

\score {
  \new Staff \line
  \layout { }
}
```

---

Or, if the slur moving to C is a necessity, you can skip all of this and just input `\slashedGrace d8-4_( <c) a>4-2-1`:

[image]

```
line = \relative c'' {
  \key g \major
  \time 3/4
  <<
    {
      \slashedGrace d8-4_( <c) a>4-2-1 <g b>4 r4 | 
    }
    \\
    {
      e,2 e'4 |
    }
  >>
}

\score {
  \new Staff \line
  \layout { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that final version does the trick. It does mess with my polyphony though – in the full version I have the two voices defined separately and then build the staff. To use this approach I have to have the two parts within the << \\ >> structure and use a silent rest in the second voice for the bars where the acciaccatura occurs.

Answer (score 3):

Put `_` before the `(` which represents the slur.

```
\version "2.18.2"

{
\time 3/4
\key g \major
\acciaccatura d''8_( <c'' a'>4) <g'b'> r4
}
```

If Lilypond does the opposite, and curves the slur down when you want it up, put a `^` before the `(`.

Comment: This gives a slur down, but also leaves the acciaccatura slur in place at the top of the construct.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone for the suggestions. They have helped me narrow down the issues.

I have now found a way to get the look I want:

```
\override Flag.stroke-style = #"grace"   d8_(-4   <c) a>4  -2 -1
   <g b>4 e4 \rest
```

Which generates:

[image]

Its slightly more complicated than I'd have liked, but there you go. Of course, if anyone can spot an easier solution I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: But that hasn't solved your problem: Your d'' is not an acciaccatura, but a full quaver/eighth. It's made the following stem-up chords a quaver too late. If there had been a third crotchet/quarter in that upper line, it would have straddled the bar line and the subsequent layout would have gone haywire.

Comment: True, but it is the least wrong to read (to my eyes). After far more reading of the documentation than I should have to do, I'm beginning to think that the issue is related to the way Lilypond deals with polyphony and I may have to add a temporary second voice to hold the a in the chord.

Comment: This isn't right at all, look at the position of the bass note